# Bug related to privileges

Tags: bug

I am new on Stack Overflow and am really enjoying the site.

Recently when I had 48 reputation points I was notified that I have earned the privilege of commenting anywhere, which was not there at that time. I've got it when I surpassed the 50 reputation points mark.

Comment: If you look at June 13 on your Reputation  you'll see you got zero that day. This indicates some action, the reverse of that action, and nothing else happening on that day. From that you went, briefly, to sufficient reputation to generate that message.